# How to copy/paste entities with QGIS Graphic Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Which kind of model create to copy selected entities from one layer to another layer using QGIS Graphic Modeler?

Comment: Most (if not all) processing algorithms return new layers so adding to an existing layer might be complicated. otherwise a solution that creates a new output layer would be to use both "Extract selected features" on the layer A with selected entities and "Merge vector layers" between output of "Extract selected features" and layer B. Which would give you the right result but in a new layer.